# 12VAC-5VDC regulator, but L7805CV doesn't work properly

Tags: voltage-regulator, 7805

[image]

Hi everyone. I am trying to make 12VAC - 5VDC power supply. However when plugged in, voltage between L7805CV in - ground was 4V while output was 1V.

I have test 7805 separately and it works correctly though. The rectifier and filter without 7805 also work correctly.

What was possibly wrong here?

Comment: *What was possibly wrong here?* - something else.

Comment: Check the AC input to the bridge. Measure the DC output of the bridge. It should be almost \$ \sqrt 2 V_{AC} \$.

Comment: Maybe you hooked the bridge output backwards. The circuit you show should work, so either it's not actually what you say it is, or something is defective.

Comment: Did you measure the 4V/1V with or without a load connected to the regulated 5V output?

Comment: @Transistor, ocrdu I will reply for you guys tomorrow, but thanks for suggestion ^^.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How strange is that I also think like you when I measure the voltage between capacitor and it shows negative value instead of positive. But from my understanding, the capacitor should be damaged (explosion, etc...)??? But it not. I haven't try hooked backwards cause I afraid it will be exploded :(

Comment: @Transistor The DC output without 7805 was correct. With 7805 (No load), it falls to 4V as I said before. Moreover, I notice that I just turned on for 10 sec and it became hot quickly (I had added heatsink). With the output without load was 1V, was it because of the efficiency 4/12sqrt(2) ~ 6%, which is 94% of heat?

Comment: Update: The problem was that @SpehroPefhany indicated. So I hooked capacitor in opposite all the times but it wasn't blow, just a bit bulging.

Comment: So when the 7805 input drive opposite source, the situation will be like that? @Transistor

Comment: It depends on the internal working and protection of the regulator. If it was not destroyed then you are fortunate.

Comment: @Transistor My yang beat my yin today ^^ Thanks for your reply.